# Logit Model for panel data [r]

Tags: r, logistic, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, spatial

I would like to ask preferably preferably econometrics and statistics community about logit model for panel data.

When dealing with panel data one must take into account individual effects (individual heterogenity) of each cross-sectional unit,
when we suppose that individual effects are correlated with indipendent variable(s) we use fixed effect approach, that is each cross sectional unit gets its own intercept, or within transformation, where we eliminate individual heterogenity from equation.

For panel data in R, very good package is `plm` that does pretty much of panel data models, 
when having binary dependent variable we can do something like linear probability model, when we would use within model from `plm` on dummy dependent variable as a baseline model.

What are your best packages that you can recommend for panel data models with binary dependent variable, 
I found `bife` package and paper for it :[fixed effect logit](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/145837/1/VfS_2016_pid_6909.pdf). Are there another packages and papers for it in R for panel data that account for individual heterogenity in models?
I know about `lme4`, `lmerTest` but I do not know if these models account for it.

Also does anyone know about package and documentation for Spatial panel data logit?, I know
there is package `splm` for spatial panel data

Answer (score 0):

Knowing from Panel data Econometrics with R , written by Yves Croissant & Giovanni Millo.

for binomial panel data, random effect you can use pglm,

fixed effect can use clogit from survival package.